# Getting error message on Cpanel using Imagick

Tags: php, svg, cpanel, imagick

I am using Imagick to edit and save svg image.
I am getting an error when I save svg image after having croped it.

Here is my code to operate svg images:

```
 $image = new Imagick();
 $image->readImage($path1);    
 $image -> cropImage($rw*11.2, $sw*7.7, 0, 0);   
 $image->writeImage('Cvilogpdfbackend/core/images/tempimage/'.$targetfile.'.svg');
```

When i call this function, I am getting bellow error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ImagickException: delegate failed
> `'potrace' --svg --output '%o' '%i'' @
> error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1897 in
> /home/civilogc/public_html/resizeimage.php:19 Stack trace:
> #0 /home/civilogc/public_html/resizeimage.php(19): Imagick->writeimage('Cvilogpdfbacken...')
> #1 {main}   thrown in /home/civilogc/public_html/resizeimage.php on line 19

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to use mainly bitmap/raster based image processing library (ImageMagick) to modify vector SVG images?

1. Let me first point you to do the right way:

ImageMagick should be mostly used for reading and writing bitmap images and for creating/writing SVG images (and other vector based format if required, e.g. EPS, PDF etc).
Instead of using ImageMagick/Imagick for your conversion (changing vector image to bitmap and back again - losing quality) just read your image for example with this code:

```
$image = file_get_contents($path1);
$svg_dom = new DOMDocument();

$tmp_obj = $svg_dom->getElementsByTagName("svg")->item(0);

$svg_width = floatval($tmp_obj->getAttribute("width"));
$svg_height = floatval($tmp_obj->getAttribute("height"));
$svg_viewbox = floatval($tmp_obj->getAttribute("vieWBox"));
```

and then I suggest you just calculate the new viewBox with your cropping adjustment (create a function for that) and set it back, optionally set new width and height as well:

```
$svg_viewBox = calculateCroppedView($svg_viewbox, $new_width, $new_height, $top, $left); 
$tmp_obj->setAttribute("viewBox", $svg_viewBox);
$tmp_obj->setAttribute("width", $new_width."px");
$tmp_obj->setAttribute("height", $new_height."px");

file_put_contents('Cvilogpdfbackend/core/images/tempimage/'.$targetfile.'.svg', $svg_dom->saveXML());
```

**Note:** you are not really cropping the SVG image (SVG elements), just changing the view (e.g. zoom) to it. Converting all cut paths, shapes, text etc is possible but would require a lot of coding. Either way the goal is to keep the (vector) image quality.

For an excellent explanation of the SVG viewBox attribute read this section:

https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/#the-viewbox-attribute

2. To answer your question:

This error states that ImageMagick in your webserver cannot find or doesn't have installed the (free) potrace software that does the actual vectorization of a bitmap image.

**Note:** you need to have ImageMagick version 7 since older version just embedded bitmap images and data encoded (base64) string to the SVG image tag or maybe used a weird conversion - depending of ImageMagick version - of converting dots to 1px SVG circle tags. And ImageMagick installed needs to be the same version as Imagick as well for the mentioned reasons.

Potrace software command line is set in *delegates.xml* of the ImageMagick/Imagick installation and ImageMagick or Imagick needs to find potrace in the PATH (environment variable).

I suggest you to contact your web hosting provider to install Potrace that can be downloaded here:

http://potrace.sourceforge.net/#downloading

And then you'll have to test your script, most likely your web hosting provider will already solve the issue just by installing Potrace. Maybe a path to it will need to be added to a user/system PATH variable and that should practically solve your issue.

If not, you can try to use ImageMagick (convert or now renamed magick, main program) and potrace using exec() command in PHP yet your web hosting must allow that since it's usually forbidden in PHP configuration.

3. To go for other help:

Well, ask a question here on SO or on ImageMagick support forum that based on their main site forum (where you cannot register anymore) is now here:

https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions